# Is that possible in PHP to pass variables into a function when they are not set as parameters?

Tags: php, function, parameters

is that possible in PHP to pass variables into a function when they are not set as parameters?
I mean something like the following:

```
$pdo=PDOconnection;
$arr=someArray;

function myFunction(){
    if(no-parameters){
        $input=$pdo;
        //or
        $input=$arr; 
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this is possible. just make sure those 2 lines are before the call of myFunction().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nick's answer should work. This might be a little simpler?

```
$pdo=PDOconnection;

function myFunction($input = null){
    if($input === null){
        $input=$GLOBALS['pdo'];
    }
}
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that it prevents passing `null` as a value.

Comment: There's always going to be some value that makes no sense whatsoever to pass in, whether `null`, `false`, `true`, `0`, `"nope"` or whatever. `null` seemed to fit the example given.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`func_num_args`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) to check for the number of function arguments, and if the result is 0, get the value from the [`$GLOBALS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array e.g.

```
$foo = 4;

function myFunction () {
    if (!func_num_args()) {
        $input = $GLOBALS['foo'];
    }
    else {
        $input = func_get_arg(0);
    }
    echo "$input\n";
}

myFunction('hello');
myFunction();
```

Output:

```
hello
4
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vvtWY)